# Passing parameters to ViewModelLocator

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, dependency-injection

I have set up dependency injection using *Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection* NuGet package in my WPF application's `App.xaml.cs` and registered `MainViewModel` in it.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    protected void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs startupEventArgs)
    {
        ConfigureServices();

        var mainWindow = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }

    private void ConfigureServices()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();

        services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();

        _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

I have created a `ViewModelLocator` class to connect my `MainViewModel` with `MainWindow`. I added the ViewModelLocator to application resources in `App.xaml` and using this ViewModelLocator application resource, I have set the `DataContext` of `MainWindow.xaml` to `MainViewModel`.

**ViewModelLocator.cs**

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public ViewModelLocator(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public MainViewModel MainViewModel => CreateViewModel<MainViewModel>();

    private T CreateViewModel<T>()
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();
    }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
         xmlns:locators="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels.Locators"
         Startup="OnStartup">
    <Application.Resources>
        <locators:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    xmlns:locators="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels.Locators"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">

<Grid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

With this solution, I'm getting errors and I figured it why. ViewModelLocator needs to have a **parameterless constructor**. However, I still need to be able to get the viewmodel from `ServiceProvider` in the `CreateViewModel` method. How I'm I able to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around this problem. I created `MyDependencyInjection` class according to Singleton pattern and moved the logic from `App.xaml.cs` into it. The class looks like this.

**MyDependencyInjection.cs**

```
public class MyDependencyInjection
{
    private IServiceProvider? _serviceProvider;

    private static MyDependencyInjection? _instance;
    public static MyDependencyInjection Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(_instance == null)
                _instance = new MyDependencyInjection();
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private MyDependencyInjection()
    {
        SetupContainer();
    }

    public T GetRequiredService<T>()
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();
    }

    private void SetupContainer()
    {
        var container = new ServiceCollection();

        container.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();

        container.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();

        _serviceProvider = container.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

And updated the **ViewModelLocator** which now looks like this.

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public MainViewModel MainViewModel => CreateViewModel<MainViewModel>();

    private static T CreateViewModel<T>()
    {
        return MyDependencyInjection.Instance.GetRequiredService<T>();
    }
}
```

I removed the problem, but I feel like this is not the best solution. So I'm still curious what is the best practice for this. Thanks for suggestions.

**UPDATE**

Okay so seems like injecting dependencies through static service is not good at all. So I used uncle Google to find better solution and I found [this](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/wpf/archive/2022/02/07/dependency-injection-in-a-wpf-mvvm-application.aspx) very easy solution for my problem. Decided to revert the previous code and implement the article one.

**DISource.cs**

```
public class DISource : MarkupExtension
{
    public static Func<Type, object> Resolver { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => Resolver.Invoke(Type);
}
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    protected void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        ConfigureServices();
        DISource.Resolver = (type) => ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(type);

        var mainWindow = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }

    private void ConfigureServices()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();

        services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();

        ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

And the connection of viewmodel with view.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    xmlns:dependencyInjection="clr-namespace:MyApp.DependencyInjection"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    DataContext="{dependencyInjection:DISource Type=viewModels:MainViewModel}">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding Message}"></Label>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Did you know that Dependency Injection is a design pattern to actually solve the Service Locator problem? You should inject the dependencies instead of making them available via a static service. Your static service should not directly access the IoC container (no class should ever do this). Your ViewModelLocator is basically a wrapper around the IoC container. Don't pass the IoC container around and don''t make it globally available by sharing it as a static variable. Instead allow the IoC container to inject the dependencies properly. that's what it is designed for.

Comment: Service Locator is commonly rated as a code smell and anti-pattern. Sharing the IoC container is the exact same as the anti-pattern called Service Locator. It introduces the exact same problems. The Service Locator is really not required. Same applies to Singleton or public static instances or variables in general. They only create memory leaks. You can easily avoid all those code smells by using Dependency Injection properly. This usually involves factories (or the Abstract Factory pattern) when you need to create instances dynamically.